# How to reply to a request in cafeteria?

Tags: expressions

I blocked a chair for my friend in cafeteria. If somebody asks for the chair, can i tell them that I need this chair or is there any better way of answering?

Answer (score 2):

> Sorry. That place/seat/chair is already taken.
>
> Sorry. Someone is already sitting there.

Comment: 2nd one would be spooky! Why can't I see that person? Maybe add a dramatic gesture...